# prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1- \cos x}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1- \cos x}$ is divergent. My idea is: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1-cosx} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{2sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}}$. If I am able to prove that $2sin^2{\frac{x}{2}} \le x, x \in [0,1]$, then I'm done, because in this case $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1-cos x} \ge \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x}$, which is divergent. How to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin x\le x$ for $x\ge 0$ and $x^2\le x$ for $0\le x\le 1$, we have
$$2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} \le 2\sin \frac{x}{2} \le 2 \frac{x}{2} = x$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the tangent half-angle substitution (Weierstrass substitution). So, $$\int \frac{dx}{1- \cos x}=\int \frac{dt}{t^2}$$ So $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{1- \cos x}=\cot \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)-\cot \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)$$ $$\int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{dx}{1- \cos x}=\cot \left(\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\right)-\cot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$x \geq \sin x = 2 \sin(x/2) \cos(x/2) \geq 2\sin^2(x/2)$ on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $0 \leq 1 - \cos y$ for any $y$, for $x > 0$ you have
$$0 \leq \int_0^x (1 - \cos y)\,dy $$
This is the same as $0 \leq x - \sin x$, which means $\sin x < x$. Use that in your integral near $x = 0$.